# Does the Pokemon affect resource gathering?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

When in the field, some resources require you to throw Pokemon at them to collect, such as berry trees and ores.  I'm not very far into the game, but so far, it seems like any Pokemon I've thrown can collect it.  But is there some benefit from using specific options?  For example, would a rock or ground type maybe offer more from ores?

Comment: The resource yield is the same regardless of the pokemon you use or the resource you're gathering as far as I can tell.

Comment: I always get no more than 5 items, regardless the level/type of Pokemon I use. So I feel there's no way to affect the drops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s no evidence the Pokémon type changes the resource gathered, at the present time.

However, some things do:

- Which area you’re in. Further areas, particularly Coronet Highlands and beyond, get iron instead of some of the stone regularly.
- Glittering ores give bonuses such as iron and stardust.
- Shaking trees and ores give more resources once you defeat or capture the Pokémon that comes out.

Comment: With sparkling ores a rare item will be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there some benefit from using specific options?

Yes, but not in the way you're thinking. Using a Pokémon to gather resources raises its friendship level (as reported by Bellamy in Jubilife Village). A high friendship level is required for certain Pokémon to evolve, notably including three of the Eeveelutions (Sylveon, Umbreon, and Espeon), as well as several others. There are other ways of boosting friendship, such as using the Pokémon in battle, but gathering resources is by far the most efficient, simply because you already need to gather resources anyway for the crafting system.